# Count rows in array

Tags: java, arrays, count, rows

So I'm trying to count how many rows are in the array, but I don't knew how to do it. I wrote this code, it reads the file and puts the content into array. How can I count the rows in array?

```
public static void main(String[] args) throws IOException {

    File file = new File("array_list.csv");
    FileInputStream fin = null;

    try {

        fin = new FileInputStream(file);
        byte fileContent[] = new byte[(int)file.length()];
        fin.read(fileContent);
        String fileToArray = new String(fileContent);


        //print file
        System.out.println(fileToArray);
    } 

    finally {
        if (null != fin) {
            fin.close();
        }
    }
}
```

Here is the content of file array_list.csv

```
569, 985, 97, 13,-94,256, 31, 74, 569,
-45, 601, 29, 19,-1952, 88,256,-69, 601,
1952, 1952,-15, 5,-54, 60, 89, 91, 39,
-601,-97, -6,-26, 89,-66,-601, 26, 28,
-51,-91, 39, 88, 99, 985, -7, 39,-29,
92, 1, 92, 92, 27,-11,-601, 22,-58,
13,-92, 28,-40, 27,-73, 0, 22, 33
```

I tryed with fileToArray.length bit explipse returns an Exception

```
Exception in thread "main" java.lang.Error: Unresolved compilation problem: 
length cannot be resolved or is not a field
```

Comment: Pleae explain what you really want to do. You can use `fileContent.length`, but I'm not sure if that's what you want. (`fileToArray` in your code isn't an array at all.)

Comment: I need to count the rows then i have to show on which rows i have duplicate elements

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can pass this string param into the below code it should work.

```
int count = new StringTokenizer(fileToArray, "\r\n").countTokens();

System.out.println(count);
```

Comment: Do you have any idea how to count the colums

Comment: @wkg86 An array does not have rows, nor columns. It only has elements. Being a one dimensional structure you can only view it as a string of data. Forget about Excel it's not a suitable metaphor for programming concepts.

Answer (score 0):

it should be fileToArray.length;

Comment: It throws Exception in thread "main" java.lang.Error: Unresolved compilation problem: length cannot be resolved or is not a field

Comment: You should add the (); at the end ;)

Answer (score 0):

May be try to split the fileToArray string by comma and count a length?

```
int rowCount = fileToArray.split(",").length
```

Answer (score 0):

You actually turned your content into a string :

```
String fileToArray = new String(fileContent)
```

So you actually have to count lines (`'\n'`) of in a string.
You can do it with

```
System.out.println(d.replaceAll("\n","").length() - d.replaceAll("\n","").length());
```